# Condensed word for mysterious and beautiful universe

Tags: single-word-requests

I was writing my college essay, which is about how I discovered mathematics and how I developed it as a passion.

At one point I constructed the following sentence:

> ...Math was my Narnia.

What I wanted to say is "*Math was a beautiful subject, but I didn't discover that soon because it was hidden by some factors.*"(these some factors are discussed in the other parts of the essay).

I thought "*Narnia*" was a good word at first. But when I think more about it, I happened to not like it. Can anyone suggest a word that can meet this goal ?

Comment: I am not sure about nirvana, but utopia sounds little bit an "open world" of harmony, but later on my essay, I refer math was disguised by the school curriculum. Nirvana(as my dictionary defines it) is state of paradise or great pleasure, and I don't think that replete the target.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implicate time as a factor of your discovery of mathematical passion, you could say "Math was my diamond in the rough." It was always a beautiful subject but you didn't discover that right away.

Other options include: enchanting, alluring, captivating, enthralling.

Answer (score 0):

Shangri-La is a hidden place of unimaginable beauty, as evoked in James Hilton's 1933 Lost Horizon. So you have the metaphor for a love that needs nothing but discovering.

Math can be beautiful, even elegant, and who would know? Another Math major would.

Comment: Shangri-la had a significant downside, if you recall.